# How to make scrolling background horzintally in portrait mode in spritekit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I want to make scrolling background when the phone in the portrait mode i tried these codes but it didn't helped me in the portrait mode

```
let background1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "space")
let background2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "space")
```

In the "didMoveToView" method

```
background1.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
background1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
background1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
background1.zPosition = -15
self.addChild(background1)

background2.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
background2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
background2.position = CGPointMake(background1.size.width - 1,0)
background2.zPosition = -15
self.addChild(background2)
```

in the "override func update method

```
  background1.position = CGPointMake(background1.position.x-2, background1.position.y)
background2.position = CGPointMake(background2.position.x-2, background2.position.y)
if(background1.position.x < -background1.size.width)
{
  background1.position = CGPointMake(background1.position.x + background2.size.width , background2.position.y)
}
if(background2.position.x < -background2.size.width)
{
  background2.position = CGPointMake(background2.position.x + background1.size.height, background1.position.y) 
}
```

the problem is when the background scrolling there is a gap between the backgrounds, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would say this, where X = (1,2), is causing your problem:

```
backgroundX.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
```

You are setting your background texture's size to that of the scene's frame overwriting the original size which is inherited from the texture's source and which it needs to calculate its new position correctly.

Comment: i tried to remove the line but didn't effect on the problem

Comment: Then there is likely a problem with the logic you are using to position the sprites, are you clear on how the endless scrolling works? eg. what triggers the swap reposition of the background sprites? Perhaps you are missing something in the `if(backgroundX.position.x < -backgroundX.size.width)` test, like a `/2` ?

Answer (score 0):

You had a few errors like using height to calculate the x position of background2. This should get you headed in the right direction...

didMoveToView

```
background1.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
background1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
background1.position = CGPointZero
background1.zPosition = 0
self.addChild(background1)

background2.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
background2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
background2.position = CGPoint(x: background2.size.width, y: 0)
background2.zPosition = 0
self.addChild(background2)
```

update

```
background1.position = CGPoint(x: background1.position.x - 2, y: background1.position.y)
background2.position = CGPoint(x: background2.position.x - 2, y: background2.position.y)

if (background1.position.x <= -background1.size.width) {
   background1.position = CGPoint(x: background1.position.x + background1.size.width * 2, y: 0)
}
if (background2.position.x <= -background2.size.width) {
   background2.position = CGPoint(x: background2.position.x + background1.size.width * 2, y: 0)
}
```

In gameViewController, before you present the scene, you may also want to add

```
scene.size = view.bounds.size
```